# Organic Groups (OG): Make public group posts visible to everyone (outside the group)

Tags: organic-groups

I’m using the OG module for my site where users can create groups and make them either public or private. But one feature I miss from the group environment when creating a public group is, to make all the posts in that group visible to everyone – not only group members.

I’ve looked in the OG admin settings and found the setting “Visibility of posts:” with the radio button option to “Visibility chosen by author/editor using a checkbox on the posting form. Checkbox defaults to Public.” This function is exactly what I want but when choosing this option and try to create a post inside an open, public group, I don’t get any options to select it to be visible or not. The field just isn’t there.

I’ve browsed Google and Drupal.org for an answer and have discovered that I’m not the only one with this question. But unfortunately I haven’t been able to find a solution, so I will try again to post the issue and maybe there is something I’ve overlooked.

Any help would help.
Thanks

Sincere
- Mestika

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You control the visibility of a post through the Group_Access field.

Create a content type with Group and Group_Access fields (or add those fields to a built-in content type). Then when users create posts of this content type, they can make the content part of the group and set its Group Access to either "Public - accessible to all site users" or "Private - accessible only to group members."

Any "Public" content will be visible to anyone on the site, not just group members.